# Updating image via Dispatcher still gives "different thread owns it" error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm trying to update an Image in my UI from an event in a different thread. I'm using a Dispatcher (based on this question: [Fire events from different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315370/fire-events-from-different-thread/10315468#10315468)) to do so, but still get the "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"-Error Message at `i.Source = s;`. What's the proper way of doing this?

```
void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageSource s = e.Image;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(
        () => UpdateUI(myImage, s)
    ));
}

void UpdateUI(Image i, ImageSource s)
{
    i.Source = s;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: You are dispatching on your current thread, not the UI thread. You first need to gain access to the UI Thread dispatcher. What kind of object are you dispatching from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ImageSource created in background thread can't be assigned as source to UI control.**

And you can access `myImage.Dispatcher` to get actual dispatcher associated with image control:

```
myImage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate       
  {
     ImageSource s = e.Image;
     UpdateUI(myImage, s);
  });
```

**OR**

call `Freeze()` on `ImageSource` before assignment. Freeze objects can be accessed across thread.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it done using `Freeze()` and `ImageSource s = e.Image.Clone();`. Using the myImage.Dispatcher did not help anything.

Comment: Great..!! That was just in case `Dispatcher` wasn't correct. Main issue is the one which i added as bold in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you `ImageSource` has been created on different thread then the one you want to use it on. You can fix it by calling `Freeze()` on your `ImageSource`

```
ImageSource s = e.Image;
s.Freeze();
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it done using Freeze() and ImageSource s = e.Image.Clone();

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching on your current thread, not the UI thread. You first need to gain access to the UI Thread dispatcher. Use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)
```

instead.

Also see this question: [How do I get the UI thread Dispatcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663070/wpf-get-gui-dispatcher)

Comment: Using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` `myImage.Dispatcher` didn't improve anything. I'm now going with `Freeze()`. Thank you!